# Remote debug javaagent jar file

Tags: debugging, instrumentation, javaagents

I created a javaagent jar file and attached it with a web application (by using `-javaagent` keyword on the startup of web application). How can i possible to remote debug this javaagent with eclipse

Answer (score 1):

```
java agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=10110,suspend=y
-javaagent:pathTo/myagent.jar -cp pathTo/myApp.jar com.example
```

In Eclipse, attach the debugger to agent jar by adding the following statement to VM arguments.

```
agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=10110,suspend=y
```